# Trying to serialize object to XML

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xml-serialization

*Using WP7 & C#:*

I'm trying to convert my object(s) to XML so I can then save that file to SkyDrive.  I've tried following many examples without much luck.  With this code I'm

```
 public void ConvertObjectToXmlString()
        {
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection.GetType());
            System.Xml.XmlWriter xtw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(ms);
            //System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xtw = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(ms, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            xs.Serialize(xtw, App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection[0]);

            MessageBox.Show(xtw.ToString());
        }
```

The error is in this line: `xs.Serialize(xtw, App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection[0]);`
I have a collection and in my test there is only 1 item.  However I can imagine that when I eventually release this code that I wouldn't have the index [0] set.

The error states: 
**There was an error generating the XML document**

When I go further into the error message I see the following:
**Cannot assign object of type OilChangeApplication.vehicle to an object of type System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[OilChangeApplication.vehicle, OilChangeApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].**

vehicleItemsCollection is a collection of vehicle... What do I need to do to get some XML so I can upload this?

Comment: What does your vehicleItem model look like? If memory serves, you need to do a little bit of metadata markup in your model so that the serializer knows how to handle your object type.

Comment: Are referring to attributes?  Right now it has none.

Comment: @Dillie-O I think you're talking about adding `[XmlSerializable]` (aka XmlSerializableAttribute) to the model class definition. It's useful, but not the cause of this error.

Comment: @jv42 DOH! You're right. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error seems very explicit with a slight translation from compiler speak: 
*Cannot assign object of type `OilChangeApplication.vehicle` to an object of type `ObservableCollection<OilChangeApplication.vehicle>`.*

It means your indexing of the collection cause the error, here:

```
xs.Serialize(xtw, App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection[0]);
```

Because instead of passing an `ObservableCollection<...>` as you told the serializer above in this part: `new XmlSerializer(App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection.GetType());`, you're passing an instance of your model class.

Thus you can either just remove the `[0]` or change the type you're passing to the serializer and the error will disappear.

```
xs.Serialize(xtw, App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection);
```

or

```
 var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(OilChangeApplication.vehicle.GetType());
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you serializing Item of collection. To serialize all collection you need to pass it:

```
xs.Serialize(xtw, App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection);
```

To clarify. By this:

```
XmlSerializer(App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection.GetType());
```

You specify that serializer can serialize objects of type:

```
ObservableCollection<OilChangeApplication.vehicle>
```

And you passing to serialize instance of `OilChangeApplication.vehicle` not the collection of `OilChangeApplication.vehicle` instances.

---

And if you want to serialize just one object then you need to "tell" serializer that you will serialize `OilChangeApplication.vehicle`:

```
XmlSerializer(typeof(OilChangeApplication.vehicle));
```

Now you can serialize just one object:

```
xs.Serialize(xtw, App.ViewModel.vehicleItemsCollection[0]);
```